# Visual Studio debugger memory search not working

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, visual-studio-debugging

When I try to debug my program, I want to look at the memory where its stored, but when I search for it, theres nothing stored.

Example:

```
aVar byte 23d
```

When I debug and search through the memory 1 window, I would type &aVar. I'd assume it'd take me to its memory location but it just brings me to a memory location with 0123456789ABCDEF stored in memory. Any help?

I've tried to debug the program on a lab computer, and I got the same results as well, I cant search memory, I dont think its even writing to memory.

Comment: `aVar byte 23d` in `.data` will make that byte part of your executable, so it's already there when your program starts.  Are you doing this search after running the program, but stopped at a breakpoint before the first instruction, so nothing can have overwritten that byte yet?

Comment: I created a small project set this up. Stopped on the first instruction and put `&aVar` in the `memory 1` tab and it did show me a memory address with 0x17 (23d) in it. Are you sure the code you wrote didn't accidentally overwrite the memory `aVar` is located at? If you set a breakpoint at the first instruction of the program what does it show for `&aVar`?

Comment: I did what you said with the breakpoint, and still it doesn't show up in memory, it is in .data, and it shows up when I use the watch tab

Answer (score 2):

I add the code  `aVar byte 23d` into my .asm file for test in VS2022 and I can see the the memory address in memory window as expected. You can compare the difference between our steps or follow my steps to recreate .asm file to test . Below are my steps.

1 create .asm file and add the following code

```
; program 3.1
; sample Assembly program - MASM (64-bit)

extern ExitProcess:PROC


.data
aVar byte 23d

.code
main PROC          
                         
  add aVar, 0
  call ExitProcess
main ENDP
END
```

2 debug with x64 and type  `&aVar` in memory window

[image]

If it doesn’t work for you ,you also could provide your screenshot of your memory window with the result `0123456789ABCDEF`  for further analyzing the issue.

Comment: This ended up working for me, thank you!

Comment: Glad to know my sample code works on your side. If possible, you could also accept the answer, this will help other users who has the same issue.